# Removing loops in numpy for a simple matrix assignment

Tags: python, numpy, loops

How can I remove loops in this simple matrix assignment in order to increase performance?

```
nk,ncol,nrow=index.shape
for kk in range(0,nk):
   for ii in range(0,nrow):
       for jj in range(0,ncol):
           idx=index[kk][ii][jj]
           counter[idx][ii][jj]+=1
```

I come from C++ and I am finding it difficult to adapt to numpy's functions to do some very basic matrix manipulation like this one. I think I have simplified it to a one dimensional loop, but this is still too slow for what I need and it seems to me that there is got to be a more direct way of doing it. Any suggestions? thanks

```
for kk in range(0,nk):
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ncol),np.arange(nrow))
    counter[index[kk,:,:].flatten(),yy.flatten(),xx.flatten()]+=1
```

Comment: Your loop makes no sense. Consider sharing an example.

Comment: @ps95 maybe if I explain where the loop comes from?. I have a matrix Temperature with dimensios (time,x,y) and values given by a set of indexes representing temperature ranges (0,1,2,3,..nranges). I want to compute for each x,y (earth location) how many times a given range has appeared in time. To do that I use a counter matrix initialized to 0 with dimension (nranges, x,y) and simply count the number of times each range appears in the Temperature matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are looking for this:

```
uniq, counter = np.unique(index, return_counts=True, axis=0)
```

The `uniq` should give you unique set of `x,y`s (`x,y` will be flattened into a single array) and `counter` corresponding number of repetitions in the array `index`

***EDIT***:

Per OP's comment below:

```
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ncol),np.arange(nrow))
idx, counts = np.unique(np.vstack((index.flatten(),np.repeat(yy.flatten(),nk),np.repeat(xx.flatten(),nk))), return_counts=True,axis=1)
counter[tuple(idx)] = counts
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying our suggestion with a simple example

Comment: Thank you. I am comparing your approach  using a simple example. I use `index=np.zeros((2,2,2))`  and I  get `counter=[[[2. 2.], [2. 2.]],[[0. 0.],[0. 0.]]]` with the initial loop as would be expected. Using you approach i get `uniq=[[[0 0], [0 0]]` and `counter= [[0 0],[0 0]]],[[[0 0],[0 0]]]` which I do not really know how to interpret.

Comment: @SandiaDeDia I see, you still can do that loop without loop, but it is quite a strange loop.

Comment: Thank you @Ehsan, I just tried a couple of examples and it seems to be working!!!. I will try to understand what you are doing.... grrrr....it is a bit frustrating  that such a obvious thing using loops becomes so different when using numpy. Thanks