# Histogram over a given axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D matrix Temp[time,x,y] representing temperatures over a region at different times.
I want to count the number of times the temperature is in a given range `[t0, t1, t2, ..., tn]`. That is, I want to compute the histogram of Temp[time,x,y] as a matrix HISTO such that:

```
Histo[0,x,y] = the number of times Temp[:,x,y] is in a range t0-t1
Histo[1,x,y] = the number of times Temp[:,x,y] is in a range t1-t2
```

What I have tried:

1. looping through each (x,y) and use `np.histogram` on Temp[:,x,y]
2. looping through each range and compute `np.count_nonzero((Temp>tn) & (Temp<tm), axis=0)`

Is there any other way of doing this? can I use hitogram over a given axe? ranges could be equally spaced if necesary.

Comment: "What I have tried..." Please [edit] your question to include code to go along with your verbal descriptions.

Comment: Is the range equidistant? (Is t1-t0==t2-t1==t3-t2==...?)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46374159/4975981

Comment: Thank you @Ehsan, yes I think it is. I have also been working on a solution using a code you posted some time ago as a reply to another question I asked.  :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62629682/removing-loops-in-numpy-for-a-simple-matrix-assignment

Comment: @SandiaDeDia does the answers not include what you are looking for? From my understanding, the recommended solution is direct answer (minus the change in the axis you might need to do or simply transpose). Please let us know if it is not directly what you are looking for and we can help better. Thank you